# Authorising another server to write to a firebase node

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase has well-documented rules to allow only users with authentication to read/write from/to nodes. I am using OpenShift to setup a CRON server that will occasionally ping my Firebase database and write values to a node. How do I enforce the rule that only my server will be able to write to that node? Do I have to enforce some sort of admin privilege. Or pass a secure key?

My search yielded this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535850/firebase-rules-to-allow-server-to-write). However, I think that question addresses a different problem.

Comment: A combination of the question/answer you linked to and [this q&a on server authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240940/how-do-you-authenticate-a-server-to-firebase) should be all that is needed. If you're having trouble getting it to work, show what you've tried and it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Read through this document. It might help what you are trying to do! https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/